# How to change 'new String(Base64.encodeBase64("ABCD".getBytes())); (java)' into Node.js?

Tags: node.js, base64

In Java, I have below code

```
String plainCredentials = "ABCD";
String base64Credentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredentials.getBytes()));
```

I'd like to change it into `Node.js`
This is how I am trying

```
var authentication = new Buffer.from("ABCD");
base64Credentials = authentication.toString('base64');
```

But the result is coming wrong.
How can I change the above `Java` code into `Node.js` code ?

Comment: the default encoding between java and node could be the difference. See if this helps: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think, below code should give you the correct result (Its the same one as yours just one liner).

```
const base64Credentials = Buffer.from('ABCD').toString('base64');
```

**Output:** QUJDRA==

If not then please edit your question and post the string which you are getting in your java program.